# Removing empty cells when using as.character in R

Tags: r

I have a table that look like this

```
A   B   C
AB ABC  CBS
AB      ABC
   ADS  
        BBB
```

A want to use the columns as a character so is used this

```
 A= as.character(table$A)
```

this results in `c(“AB”, “AB”, “”)` my goal was `c(“AB”, “AB”)`, so without the empty cell `""`.   To get wit of the empty cell I used this   `A=A[!A==""]` which gives the results I want, but there must be a more elegant way of accomplishing the same goal.

May questions are 1) is there a better way of removing empty characters/cells.
Or more general 2) is there a way to transform the 3 columns (A,B,C) into characters A, B, C without the empty cells.

Thanks

```
 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
         $ A: Factor w/ 2 levels "","AB": 2 2 1
         $ B: Factor w/ 3 levels "","ABC","ADS": 2 1 3
         $ C: Factor w/ 3 levels "ABC","BBB","CBS": 3 1 2
```

Comment: what exactly are the empty cells before `as.character`??? (in other words, please give us `str(table)` at a minimum)

Comment: @baptiste, the data was loaded from excel.

Comment: Then I think there could be a better way to read the data in the first place.

Comment: If you import your data from an .xls file, what do the empty cells look like in your Excel sheet? That information would truly help in solving your problem.

Comment: @flowla, they are empty.

Comment: And how do you exactly load this file into R?

Comment: @flowla, I load the file as a CSV file,  read.csv(file="C:........",head=TRUE,sep=";")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the argument `na.strings` during data import. Also, instead of using `read.csv()`, you could write `read.csv2()` which uses `sep = ";"` by default.

```
# Import data
data <- read.csv2("/path/to/data.csv", header = TRUE,
                  na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(data)

'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: chr  "AB" "AB" NA NA
 $ B: chr  "ABC" NA "ADS" NA
 $ C: chr  "CBS" "ABC" NA "BBB"

# Exclude NAs
as.character(na.exclude(data$A))

[1] "AB" "AB"
```

Comment: You're right, it is just for clarity purposes that I added `as.character` before the `na.exclude` statement. Without it, there would be some (in our case unnecessary) additional lines of output in the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to read your data set again, you can use:

```
# not in ('') or ("")
A <- table$A[!table$A %in% '']
```